# add 1 to zIndex on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to make this so it adds 1 to the zIndex on every click so it's like 101, 102, 103...

```
st[0].onclick = function () {

        var z = 100;
        document.getElementById(current).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(current).style.zIndex = z++;
        current = state;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your z outside of your function.

```
var z = 100;

st[0].onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById(current).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(current).style.zIndex = z++;
        current = state;
    };
```